# EnableValidator in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a validator in my `Webform.aspx`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="val1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"/>
```

In my jquery, I have a function which attempts to disable it called by a button in the markup

```
btnclick = function()
{
    var a = $('#val1');
    alert(a); //alerts [object Object]
    ValidatorEnable(a, false); //gets a console error
}
```

when this function is executed, I get an error in the console (I am using Google Chrome), saying that `uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined`

Is this saying that my var a is undefined? ... but that makes no sense since it is alerting an `[object Object]`

I also did `alert(a.length`) which gave me `1` as expected.

Comment: I just had this problem yesterday and couldn't figure it out. Went with CustomValidator, that may be a viable option for you as well.

Comment: @AndrewWalters I am leaning towards that however I saw that this is a viable solution. I am just confused as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `ValidatorEnable(a[0], false)`? ValidatorEnable needs an element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Usually the requiredfield validators don't need to be invoked with a custom javascript, they will be invoked with a submit button.  Why invoke with .js?

Comment: @jrummell that appears to be the solution thanks!

Comment: @JonHarding this particular validation rule may depend upon the value of another field.

Comment: @Rhs excellent, I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ValidatorEnable` needs an element, not a jQuery object. You can get the first matched element using an index.

```
var a = $('#val1');
ValidatorEnable(a[0], false);
```

Comment: Its not working for me. its able to pick control ID like ValidatorEnable(a, false); but its not able to disable Comparevalidator